# How to get all the selected values from a multiselect input?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel and I tried to used `die(var_dump('$request->input('users')));` to check the data that are selected using a multiselect input. When I selected all 3 users, the output was just showing the last user id like this

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

This is the input. The name was set as `user[0]` because the inputs can be multiple depending on the user how many multiselect input is needed

```
<select class="form-control user" id="user" name="user[0]" multiple="">
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        @if (old('user') == $user->id)
            <option value="{{ $user->id }}" selected="">{{ ucwords($user->name) }}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

And this below if from the controller

```
$users = array();
$user = $request->input('user');
$user = implode(',', $user);
```

Comment: use ``dd()`` helper method to dump and die in ``Laravel`` instead of using ``die(var_dump('$request->input('users')));`` . Example: ``dd($request->input('users'))``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the input name setup as the syntax for adding an element to an array:

```
 name="user[]"
```

Then you will get your array from `$request->input('user', []);`

If you are going to have multiple different selects you can use the index in them if you wish:

```
 name="user[0][]"
 name="user[1][]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have make your input field as array.

**blade.php file**

```
<select class="form-control user" id="user" name="user[]" multiple="">
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        @if (old('user') == $user->id)
            <option value="{{ $user->id }}" selected="">{{ ucwords($user->name) }}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach

</select>
```

**controller**

```
$users = array();
$users = $request->input('user',[]);
$users = implode(',', $users);
```

Why are you converted array into string here `$users = implode(',', $users);`?

Comment: Thank you. This is also a correct answer. I found a question same as mine and the correct answer for their question is by using implode so I tried it out.

Comment: It's depend on requirements there was need implode so they were used it,But in your requirements no need it Because you are display it using  foreach loop and foreach loop work on array.Thanks